# Mobile First 7.1 FWLSE0376E: JWS signed ClientId signature does not match the client ID

Tags: java, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

Intermittent issue occurs, While handshake between **iOS Native** Application to **MobileFirst 7.1.0.00.20180425-1124**

**Findings**

1. Found out the "scope" query parameter is sent to the server as an empty string.

Here i am trying to WWW-authenticate, based Custom authrealm.

**Actual URL**

```
    http://localhost:8080/BA/authorization/v1/authorization?client_id=rr4a6042193a89c44a8d2415874ef6d279123456
 &isAjaxRequest=true&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmfpredirecturi&response_type=code&scope=
```

**Excpected URL**

```
    http://localhost:8080/BA/authorization/v1/authorization?client_id=rr4a6042193a89c44a8d2415874ef6d279123456
&isAjaxRequest=true&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmfpredirecturi&response_type=code&scope=UserAuthRealm
```

2. As per **worklight-jee-library.jar** --
   com.worklight.authorization.endpoint.token.**TokenEndpoint**

public key is **not matched**.

```
if (!Bytes.areEqual(clientPublicKey, jwsParts.getPublicKey().getEncoded())){
   logger.debug(method, "JWS signature does not match the client ID");
   return false;
 } 

 return true;
```

3. So far issue occurred in **iOS 12** devices. not in other version of OS

And please find configuration used..

**application-descriptor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <nativeIOSApp xmlns="http://www.worklight.com/native-ios-descriptor" applicationId="**App" bundleId="com.xxx.mobile" id="**App" platformVersion="7.1.0.00.20160528-1648" securityTest="CustomAppAuthenticityAutoProvTest" version="7.2">

    <displayName>iOS</displayName>
    <description>iOS Mobile App</description>

    <accessTokenExpiration>1800</accessTokenExpiration>
    <userIdentityRealms>UserAuthRealm</userIdentityRealms>
    <pushSender password="*********"/>
    <licenseAppType>APPLICATION</licenseAppType>
    <targetCategory>B2C</targetCategory>
</nativeIOSApp>
```

**conf/authenticationConfig.xml**

```
<realm name="UserAuthRealm" loginModule="CustomAuthLoginModule">
   <className>com.ibm.mfp.CustomUserAuthenticator</className>
</realm>
```

**worklight.properties**

```
mfp.session.independent=true
mfp.attrStore.type=database
```

**Device Details**

```
 {
    "x-wl-clientlog-env":"iOSnative",
    "x-wl-clientlog-appversion":"7.0","
    "x-wl-clientlog-model":"iPhone8,2",
    "x-wl-clientlog-osversion":"12.0",
    "x-wl-clientlog-appname":"iOSWLApp"
  }
```

**Response**

```
{
   "error_description":"Client authentication failed",
   "error":"invalid_client"
}
```

**Message.log**

00002171 com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthorizationFilterUtils
**E FWLSE0376E: JWS signed ClientId signature does not match the client ID**

0000285b com.worklight.oauth.validation.Validator
I OAuthTAI Authentication failed with Status = 401, WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="imfAuthentication", **scope=""**

**Trace.log**

[1/27/19 19:08:25:434 GST] 0000285b id=         com.worklight.oauth.validation.Validator                     > validate ENTRY

[1/27/19 19:08:25:434 GST] 0000285b id=         com.worklight.oauth.validation.Validator                     1 validate missing_authorization

[1/27/19 19:08:25:434 GST] 0000285b id=         **com.worklight.oauth.validation.Validator                     I processErrorCode OAuthTAI Authentication failed with Status = 401, WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="imfAuthentication", scope=""**

[1/27/19 19:08:25:434 GST] 0000285b id=         com.worklight.adapters.rest.WLShouldCompressPredicat         1 shouldCompress Request: http://localhost:8080/MA/adapters/AccessAdapter/getDetails disableCompressionAttr=null
[1/27/19 19:08:25:434 GST] 0000285b id=         com.worklight.adapters.rest.WLShouldCompressPredicat         1 shouldCompress Request: http://localhost:8080/MA/adapters/AccessAdapter/getDetails acceptGZipEncoding=true

[1/27/19 19:08:25:435 GST] 0000285b id=         com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal                   1 unset unset ProjectLocal

[1/27/19 19:08:25:435 GST] 0000285b id=         com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal                   3 unset **java.lang.Throwable
        at com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal.unset(BaseProjectLocal.java:114)**
        at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.MFPRequestListener.requestDestroyed(MFPRequestListener.java:24)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletRequestDestroyed(WebApp.java:2747)

Comment: By intermittent, do you mean the same device works sometimes, but get the "invalid_client" error sometimes? And whenever you get this error, is this immediately after the application takes an update - via AppStore/iTunes/Xcode?

Comment: @RamakrishnanM Are you using clusters in MF Server or there any load balancers ? You facing this issue with local server too ?

Comment: @VittalPai i am facing this issue in local server itself

Comment: @RamakrishnanM Interesting, Can you open a case with IBM Support on this.

Comment: @VivinK This error occurs in randomly on same device. The device which generates this error when reinstalled with the same build it doesn't show any error. and app isn't pushed to the appstore yet.

Comment: @VittalPai Yes I have already raised this to IBM. Now i have added one more findings. please check